# gstreamer cannot capture color images

Tags: raspberry-pi, gstreamer, usb-camera

I am trying to use 4 camera on rPI 4. Therefore, i use a Gstreamer and i don't know how it do  but my camera is always send gray capture. Can Gstreamer change camera's microcontroller? and if yes, how can i fix this issue?

thank you

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! "video/x-raw, format=YUY2" ! videoconvert ! "video/x-raw, format=NV12" ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

i tried this command but it doesnt work, still gray capture

Comment: what does `gst-device-monitor-1.0` give you? It should tell you all the formats the camera supports.

Comment: gst-device-monitor-1.0 return is just YUY2 format